# Java - Downloading Wikipedia Articles

Tags: java, networking, wikipedia

This is my first experiment that uses a network API and connects to the internet. 
I tried to write a program that gives you an article of wikipedia directly by typing the name.

You can get an article like this:

```
java ArticleSupplier computer science
java ArticleSupplier captain underpants
```

If you have tips for me how to improve the performance or how to make a better structure, I would be thankful!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class ArticleSupplier {
    private String nameOfArticle; // will be the name of the created document
    private String urlName;
    private URL url;
    private String article;

    public ArticleSupplier(String[] urlComponents) {
        // initialize article
        article = "";

        // initialize urlName and nameOfArticle
        urlName = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";
        nameOfArticle = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < urlComponents.length; i++) {
            urlName += urlComponents[i];
            urlName += "_";

            nameOfArticle += urlComponents[i];
            nameOfArticle += " ";
        }
        urlName = urlName.substring(0, urlName.length() - 1);
        nameOfArticle = nameOfArticle.substring(0, nameOfArticle.length() - 1);

        // initialize url
        try {
            url = new URL(urlName);
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getArticle() {
        try(InputStream inputStream = url.openStream(); Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream)) {
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                article += scanner.next() + "\n";
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void saveAsHTML() {
        String filename = nameOfArticle + ".html";
        try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filename);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {
            bufferedWriter.write(article);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArticleSupplier as = new ArticleSupplier(args);
        as.getArticle();
        as.saveAsHTML();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a minor point: I prefer "top down" source code in Java.  Placing `main` at the end of a source listing is older Pascal style and looks a bit odd in Java.  (And we only did that because older compilers couldn't handle forward references.)

Comment: Also, using `Scanner` which uses regex under the hood is going to be somewhat inefficient.  Look at just using a `BufferedReader` directly.  Also look at [setting the buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614962/tweaking-performance-of-javas-sockets) to something large, like 64k bytes.  However, Wikipedia articles tend to be somewhat short (like, less than 1 megabyte) and so the actual performance of reading a network socket may not matter much here.  (Sorry for the short comments, I don't have a lot of time atm.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advice 1**

```
urlName = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";
```

I suggest you make that magic string a static constant:

```
private static final String WIKIPEDIA_MAIN_URL =
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";
```

**Advice 2**

```
for(int i = 0; i < urlComponents.length; i++) {
    ...
```

According to (common) Java coding conventions there must be a single space between `for` and the opening brace:

```
for (int i ...
   ^
```

**Advice 3**

```
for (int i = 0; i < urlComponents.length; i++) {
```

may be written as

```
for (String urlComponent : urlComponents) {
```

**Advice 4**

```
for(int i = 0; i < urlComponents.length; i++) {
    urlName += urlComponents[i];
    urlName += "_";

    nameOfArticle += urlComponents[i];
    nameOfArticle += " ";
}
urlName = urlName.substring(0, urlName.length() - 1);
nameOfArticle = nameOfArticle.substring(0, nameOfArticle.length() - 1);
```

You are essentially repeating yourself; I would do this instead:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String separator = "";

for (String urlComponent : urlComponents) {
    stringBuilder.append(separator).append(urlComponent);
    separator = "_";
}

this.articleName = stringBuilder.toString();
String urlName = WIKIPEDIA_MAIN_URL + stringBuilder.toString();
```

**Advice 5**

```
public void getArticle() {
    try(InputStream inputStream = url.openStream(); Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream)) {
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            article += scanner.next() + "\n";
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Why read one "word" at a time when you can read an entire line. Also, whenever building such strings, [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) will be much more efficient:

```
public void getArticle() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream())) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine()); // <-- note the builder
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.article = stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

**Alternative implementation**

Gathering all the advices, I had this in mind:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class ArticleSupplier {

    private static final String WIKIPEDIA_MAIN_URL =
            "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";

    private String articleName;
    private URL url;
    private String article;

    public ArticleSupplier(String[] urlComponents) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = "";

        for (String urlComponent : urlComponents) {
            stringBuilder.append(separator).append(urlComponent);
            separator = "_";
        }

        this.articleName = stringBuilder.toString();
        String urlName = WIKIPEDIA_MAIN_URL + stringBuilder.toString();

        try {
            this.url = new URL(urlName);
        } catch(MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getArticle() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream())) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.article = stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public void saveAsHTML() {
        String filename = articleName + ".html";

        try (BufferedWriter writer =
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename))) {
            writer.write(article);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArticleSupplier as = new ArticleSupplier(args);
        as.getArticle();
        as.saveAsHTML();
    }
}
```